# List prevent breaking

Tags: list, html, contenteditable

How do I prevent a contenteditable list from breaking the list(restarting the numbering) when I press an enter in an empty line?

Edit :So sorry about not providing enough details. So stupid of me!! I was kind of frustrated.

The above question is with reference to ordered list in HTML. By default, if you press enter on one of the list items, another list item is added but if  you press enter again and it that line is empty, the list will break and a new ol tag is added and hence a new list starts with numbers from 1. What I'm looking for is a way to prevent the this behaviour and instead make the browser create a new list item even after an enter key on a blank line.

I understand that one of the solutions is to add a space or something using JavaScript but I just wanted to make sure that there are no other built in methods before I spend CPU resources on an extra script.

Comment: Using what? You need to be more specific, please read the FAQ on asking questions and edit this.

Comment: I have no idea what technology you're talking about as your question is about as clear as mud, but be advised that the behaviour you describe is _normal_ for WYSIWYG editors, and it would be [surprising to the user](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) if this were not to happen in yours. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I don't think that's what `<ol>` and `contenteditable="true"` are designed for.